# Pythonic solution to having parametrized values associated with a fixture. (pytest)

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

I have a fixture, get_cls(), which I use throughout a testing package. it defines a class with a few very simple methods (normally just returning their arguments) and returns it. For most tests this is sufficient so I would like to keep this fixture as is. Its also used frequently so I would rather not create a class and parametrize it as it would involve typing out a lot of redundant lines.

For a few tests, I need to take the test and parametrize some valid method names of the class, some invalid method names of the class, some valid and invalid parameters and also some related callables. I could write something this like:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
   'method, args, callable',
   [(method, (1, 2), lambda x: str(x)],
)
def test_something(get_cls, method, args, callable):
   # some code doing a test.
```

However, this feels dodgy, the parametrized values are always highly related to the class produced by the fixture, so naturally I feel they should be tied to said fixture in someway. 
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would say you overthink this - if it works that way, it is totally fine. As you will call the methods on your test class inside the test, the coupling will be obvious enough. Is there another reason except the dodgy feeling to not do it this way?

Comment: Nope, just aware that it doesnt necessarily look clear to a new reader/ easy to rewrite one without noticing the others relationship to it